# Storig data in C++ like dictionaries in python

Tags: python, c++

I am currently learning c++ and I am making some sort of mini game, where you have village, buildings in this village, buildings produce resources etc. 
First I made it in python but decided to start making it in c++. Python has dictionaries and it worked very well for me. ex.

```
    BUILDINGS= { 'Sawmill':{  'buildingReq': {'wood':10,'iron':10},
                    'production':{'wood':1},
                    'productionReq':{'iron':1},
                    'upgrade':'Big Sawmil',
                    'buildingTime':5},
                 'Smith':{  ......}
```

then I had:

```
 class Building():
   def __init__(self, buildingtype= '', x = 0, y = 0):
      self.buildingReq= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['buildingReq'] 
      self.production= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['production'] 
      self.productionReq= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['productionReq']


def work(self, village):
    for key in self.productionReq.keys():
        village.resource[key] = village.resource.get(key) - self.productionReq.get(key)
    for key in self.production.keys():
        village.resource[key] = village.resource.get(key) + self.production.get(key)
```

During creation of object i had function to search for building i wanted to build and all its parameters. As you can see there are diffrent types in this dictionary. In c++ i had to do 3 maps, one for diffrent sets of datatype, one for  building requirements map(string building , map(string buildingReq, map(string wood  int 10))), one for building time map etc

Right now in c++ i have someting like this

```
 std::map < std::string, std::map < std::string, std::map < std::string, int>>> buildingInfo= {
{"Sawmill", {{"buildingReq", {{"wood",15},{"iron",15}}}, {"production", { {"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}}},
{"Smith", {{"buildingReq", {{"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}, {"production", { {"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}}},
{"Big Sawmill", {{"buildingReq", {{"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}, {"production", { {"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}}},
{"Big Smith", {{"buildingReq", {{"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}, {"production", { {"wood",10},{"iron",10}}}}}
```

};

```
  std::map <std::string, int> buildingTime= {
{"Sawmill", 3},
{"Smith", 3},
{"Big Sawmill", 3},
{"Big Smith", 3}
```

};

```
   std::map <std::string, std::string> upgrades= {
{"Sawmill", "Big Sawmill"},
{"Smith", "Big Smith"}
```

};

```
   std::map<std::string, int> workersNum= {
{"Sawmmill",  10},
{"Smith", 10}


 class Building { 
    public:
std::string buildingType;
std::map<std::string, int> production;
std::map<std::string, int> buildingReq;
 };
```

And they i extract this data by

```
  for (auto x : buildingInfo) {
    if (x.first == buildingType) {
        for (auto y : x.second) {
            if (y.first == "buildingReq") {
                this->buildingReq.insert(y.second.begin(), y.second.end());
            }
            if (y.first == "production") {
                this->production.insert(y.second.begin(), y.second.end());
            }
        }break;
    }
}
```

Maybe biggest probem is not extracting data, despite may fors,  but storing it this way. In python i had one dictionary, but in c++ i have 4 maps.
How could I do someting similar in C++? or maybe there is some better way?

Comment: Consider a true class for your building, where each field (the requirements, production, upgrade, etc) is strongly typed corresponding to the type of data stored in those fields.

Comment: You'll need to explain your exact use-case a bit more then, and include a sample of the class you defined.

Comment: @nanofarad I have those fields in my class, what I need is convenient way of storing data and extracting data about those buildings.
In python i had someting like this in constructor
        self.buildingReq= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['buildingReq']
        self.production= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['production']
        self.productionReq= constants.BUILDINGS[buildingtype]['productionReq']

Comment: You can have classes that hold these constants; they can be loaded into memory e.g. at game startup. Beyond that, your issue is still not clear enough to give more detailed insights

Comment: @nanofarad I made some edits maybe it will be more clear now :) and sorry for bad editing, I am new to stackoverlow

Comment: No worries, I'll take a look and will see what I can come up with. At first glance, why isn't `buildingInfo` just a `std::map<std::string, Building>` where each `Building` contains the data that describes it? I would suggest stepping back from the question as-is, and focusing on just writing a good Building class which has useful constructors, methods, etc. After that, you can investigate how to use that class effectively.

Answer (score 0):

A big difference between programming languages is how strict their type system is. Python's type system is very loose, whereas C++ is quite strict. You should embrace this when writing C++, and make explicit types where appropriate.

As nanofarad mentioned, you should create a `class` representing a building. Instead of having yet another `std::map` to store properties of a building, you just have explicit member variables for them, each of them with the appropriate type for that property. Here's what it could look like:

```
class BuildingInfo {
public:
    std::map<std::string, int> buildingReq;
    std::map<std::string, int> production;
    std::map<std::string, int> productionReq;
    std::string upgrade;
    int buildingTime;
};
```

And then you can create your array of pre-defined building types at compile time, like so:

```
const std::map<std::string, BuildingInfo> buildings = {
    {"Sawmill",
        {
            /* buildingReq */    {{"wood", 15}, {"iron", 15}},
            /* production */     {{"wood", 1}},
            /* productionReq */  {{"iron", 1}},
            /* upgrade */        "Big Sawmill",
            /* buildingTime */   5,
        }
    },
    {"Smith",
        {
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
};
```

However, this is not optimal from a performance standpoint. A large amount of memory is wasted on the map structures and the strings themselves. And every time you have to look up the requirements for a building for example, several maps have to be traversed, resulting in rather slow code. It can be made more optimal by having numeric identifiers for buildings and resources, and using arrays instead of maps. To generate the identifiers, you can use an `enum`, for example:

```
enum Building {
    SAWMILL,
    SMITH,
    BIG_SAWMILL,
    BIG_SMITH, 
    ...
    BUILDING_COUNT
};

enum Resource {
    WOOD,
    IRON,
    ...
    RESOURCE_COUNT
};

class BuildingInfo {
public:
     std::string name;
     int buildingReq[RESOURCE_COUNT];
     int production[RESOURCE_COUNT];
     int productionReq[RESOURCE_COUNT];
     BuildingType upgrade;
     int buildingTime;
};

const BuildingInfo buildings[BUILDING_COUNT] = {
    {
        /* name */         "Sawmill",
        /* buildingReq */   {15, 15},
        /* production */    { 1,  0},
        /* productionReq */ { 0,  1},
        /* upgrade */       BIG_SAWMILL,
        /* buildingTime */  5,
    },
    {
        /* name */         "Smith",
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

However, the latter example is a bit unsafe: it's easy to get the order of the array `buildings[]` wrong compared to the `enum BuildingType`, and you can accidentily use a name from `enum ResourceType` where you should have used one from `enum BuildingType`. A compromise would be to use [`enum class`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) instead of `enum` for identifying building and resource types, and keep using `std::map` instead of arrays. It would then look like:

```
enum class Building {
    SAWMILL,
    ...,
    BIG_SMITH,
};

enum class Resource {
     WOOD,
     IRON,
};

class BuildingInfo {
public:
     std::map<Resource, int> buildingReq;
     std::map<Resource, int> production;
     std::map<Resource, int> productionReq;
     Building upgrade;
     int buildingTime;
};

const std::map<Building, BuildingInfo> buildings = {
    {Building::SAWMILL,
        {
            /* buildingReq */   {{Resource::WOOD, 15}, {Resource::IRON, 15}},
            /* production */    {{Resource::WOOD, 1}},
            /* productionReq */ {{Resource::IRON, 1}},
            /* upgrade */       Building::BIG_SAWMILL,
            /* buildingTime */  5,
        }
    },
    {Building::SMITH,
        ...
    },
    ...
};
```

Note that in all of the above examples, the member variables `buildingReq`, `production` and `productionReq` are the same type. It makes sense to make this explicit:

```
typedef std::map<Resource, int> ResourceCollection;

class BuildingInfo {
public:
     ResourceCollection buildingReq;
     ResourceCollection production;
     ResourceCollection productionReq;
     ...
};
```

You can go further and turn `ResourceCollection` into a proper `class`, with functions for adding and subtracting resource collections from each other, and so on. Creating your own types makes it easy for the compiler to type-check your code, and will catch programming errors at compile-time.